# Google-libphonenumber validating phone number Cannot read property 'isValidNumber'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to validate a phone number with google-libphonenumber but its giving me an error while trying to do it.

> console.log(phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phoneUtil.parse('202-456-1111',
>   'US')));
>                        ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValidNumber' of undefined

And thats how i'm doing the validation

```
var phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').phoneUtil
        , PNF = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberFormat
        , PNT = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberType;
console.log(phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phoneUtil.parse('202-456-1111', 'US')));
```

This code i got from a website, i couldn't find inside the api documentation, i was trying to test using this to see if it works, i couldn't find anything that gives me a direction how to validate this any phone number.

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber) you need to create `phoneUtil` like this:

```
var phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
```

Comment: well, thanks. Sometimes we miss something and some sites around miss it too. Its working.